# Cannot identify element in splinter browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I have the following snippet of HTML

```
<input type="text" name="fldLoginUserId" maxlength="15" size="10" onkeypress="return fSubmit(event);" value="" class="input_password">
```

This is part of the larger HTML. This element which I can see using Chrome - Inspect is available. However, when I try something like

```
myurl = 'xxx' # I am hiding xxx as I dont want to disclose the site here

from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)
browser.visit(myurl)
customerId = browser.find_by_name('fldLoginUserId')
```

This returns `customerId` as a empty list.

Can someone please point any mistake I am making ?

Comment: Is the element in an IFRAME? Have you tried using `$$()` and `$x()` in the dev console to test your locators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first time using Splinter with python here. Your code seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('chrome')
browser.visit('http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar')
customerId = browser.find_by_name('generator')
for objectx in customerId :
      print objectx._element.get_attribute('content')
```

Output:

```
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects/python/splinter$ python web_browser_splinter.py 
Divi v.2.5.6
WordPress 4.9.6
```

When I've asked for a non-existing value in the HTML the output is an empty list:

```
mortiz@florida:~/Documents/projects/python/splinter$ python web_browser_splinter.py 
[]
```

I've tracked your property to the site that you're probably using. That HTML is being rendered by Javascript:

```
document.write('<input type="text" name="fldLoginUserId" maxlength="15" size="13" autocomplete="off" onkeypress = "return fSubmit(event);" value="" oncopy="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" onpaste="return false" />')
```

And although the property exists in the HTML inspection it can't be retrieved the same way than the example I provided.

Because it's being rendered by Javascript, I guess it's something related to that and the DOM loading order.

Just a guess, maybe a good point to start.